# RewriteRule on a long, ugly URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am trying to redirect http://domain.com/partners/index.php?00N600000028zDp=0016000000qp33G&00N60000002UzF5=0016000000qp33G&00N600000029PAh=0016000000qp33G&00N6000000292kr=GO%20GREEN%20AMERICA%20TV&00N60000002X3cq=1$

to another page. typically i would do this as such:

```
RewriteRule ^partners/index.php?00N600000028zDp...(shortening this)$ http://domain.com/page/ [L,NE,NC,R=302]
```

however this time it's not working. i suspect it has something to do with the ?,=,&, or % characters in the URL, but i am not sure. any advice? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the `?`) in the regex pattern in a `RewriteRule`. You need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^00N600000028zDp=0016000000qp33G&00N60000002UzF5=0016000000qp33G&00N600000029PAh=0016000000qp33G&00N6000000292kr=GO%20GREEN%20AMERICA%20TV&00N60000002X3cq=1$
RewriteRule ^partners/index.php$ http://domain.com/page/? [L,NE,NC,R=302]
```

Keep in mind that when you redirect the browser, the browser will load `http://domain.com/page/` and this redrect that you've setup doesn't touch that at all. So you'll see the contents of `http://domain.com/page/` once you get redirected.